# Reducing multiple each statements in jquery

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

So according to the selected row id (from 1 to 3), it will push each value to the appropriate array. How can I reduce those `each` statements?
for `row1` it should push to array a for `row2` it should push to array b and so on

```
    $('#buttonCheck').click(function(event){
         var a1 = []; var a2 = []; var a3 = [];
$("#row1").find("td input").each(function() {a.push(this.value); });
$("#row2").find("td input").each(function() {a.push(this.value); });
$("#row3").find("td input").each(function() {a.push(this.value); });
 });
```

html:

```
     <table>
     <tr id="row1">
          <td>1</td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
          <td>1</td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
        </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
          <td>1</td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
         <td><input  type="text"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: set one class for rows, and set a handler for inputs in it

Comment: i want to somehow check if the inputs come from first row push to a if second row push to array b, etc

Comment: how are `a`, `b` and `c` used after this code?

Comment: I get each row's inputs (as shown in my question) convert each array into string and validate each string if it is correct (validating using onclick event)

Comment: each row consists of 8 inputs, i take those inputs of each row and push them to the appropriate array. for first row i push them to array a for second row to array b and so on

Comment: Why do you want the results in three arrays? What's the point of this code? The arrays `a`, `b`, and `c` are all local to the event handler function, so you would never be able to use the results in any meaningful way.

Comment: because each row belongs to each array. The validation process checks each row if it is correct

Answer (score 1):

One option is to abstract out that common function, give it a name (e.g. `checkValues`), and then pass that function to [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), then assign the value from [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray) to each array.

Think of `map()` as creating an array where the callback function pushes a value to that array, which is what your original code does.

```js
function mapValues() {
  var z = $(this).val();
  if (z === "1" || z === "0") {
    return this.value;
  }
}

function checkValues() {
  var a = $("#row1").find("td input").map(mapValues).toArray();
  var b = $("#row2").find("td input").map(mapValues).toArray();
  var c = $("#row3").find("td input").map(mapValues).toArray();
  $('#output').html('<h4>Output:</h4>a: ['+a +'] <br/> b: ['+b+']<br/>c: ['+ c + ']');
}
$(function() { //DOM-ready
  $('#check').click(checkValues);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr id="row1">
          <td>1</td>
         <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
          <td>1</td>
         <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" value="1" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
        </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
          <td>1</td>
         <td><input  type="text" value="1" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" value="1" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
<button id="check">Check Values</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I press the "Check" and there is no output.

Comment: Interesting... which browser are you using when this happens?

Comment: @SamOnela thank you i will try to implement that on my project tomorrow. Even though i believe there is a more efficient way to to that, you created two more functions , i only have one .click event and inside that there are my each statements

Comment: I thought something like this: `$("[id^=row]").each(function(i) { a[i].push(this.value); });` changed variables to `a1 = []; a2 = []; a3 = [];`